# Changing the sign of some array values in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to write a function that takes the elements in an array and changes the sign (ex. 3 --> -3 or -3 --> 3). The thing is i have to change all of the values except the first 3 integers in the array and then display the entire array with the unchanged and changed values.
Here's my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void change_sign(int x[], int n)
{
    int *ptr[n];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = &x[i+3];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {        
        x[i] = *ptr[i] * (-1);
        printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{

int arr [10] = {-5, 13, -2, 5, 8, -54, 82, -4, 9, -43};

change_sign(arr, 10);

return 0;    
}
```

This obviously doesnt work, it only shows the changed numbers and some random numbers at the end.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `except the first 3 integers`..why `i ==0` then?

Comment: Do you need to modify the array values *and then* print the original and modified values? Or can you print it, modify it in place, and then print it? Also, to negate a variable `n`, just use `n = -n` rather than `n = -1 * n`. (Either works, but the first is simpler.)

Comment: Why do you have an array of pointers (`int *ptr[n];`)?

Comment: in my example the array is {-5, 13, -2, 5, 8, -54, 82, -4, 9, -43} so the output should be {-5, 13, -2, -5, -8, 54, -82, 4,- 9, 43}. I guess the part that im stuck at is the printing the entire array, because im only printing the changed values. I made the array of pointers to see if i could change the values from index 3 and up and keeping the first 3 intact.

Comment: Start the for loop from i = 3; and then use the negation and assign back to x[i] like x[i] = -x[i]; or multiple with -1 and assign back.

Comment: if you want to have the original array as it is in main then you need to assign it to another array. so there will be 2 array parameter to this function, pass both from main, then assign y[i] = -x[i] inside function

Comment: `void change_sign(int* arr, unsigned size) { for (arr+=3; size > 3; --size, ++arr) { *arr = -(*arr); } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void change_sign(int x[], int n)
{

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(i>2)
        x[i] = -x[i];

        printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{

int arr [10] = {-5, 13, -2, 5, 8, -54, 82, -4, 9, -43};

change_sign(arr, 10);

return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, both solutions mentioned above worked like a charm, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I did, but it says my rep is too low for it to show, im sorry.

Comment: No prob. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your bug is due to out of bounds

If you don't want to use pointer, try something like

```
void change_sign(int x[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 3; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = -x[i] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the better answer